# knitr sanitises the % marker for LaTex comments and they show up in the final document

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I am writing a knitr document using xtable to get my tables. Xtable inserts by default a comment saying:

```
 "latex table generated in R 3.1.0 by stable 1.7-3 package % Thu Sep 18 14:19:21 2014"
```

This text is obviously commented out by a % symbol in xtable's output, but knitr seems to be sanitising the % by inserting a escape character "\" before it, which then is picked up by pdfLatex, resulting in the text:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.1.0 by xtable 1.7-3 package % Thu Sep 18 14:19:21 2014
```

Can I stop either knitr or xtable from doing this?

Edit: Here is an example document.

````
---
title: "knitr document"
output:
pdf_document:
keep_tex: yes
number_sections: yes
toc: yes
---
```{r load_packages,echo=FALSE,include=FALSE,results='hide',cache=TRUE}
library(xtable)
```
```{r prepare_table,echo=FALSE,results='hide'}
table <- cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))
colnames(table) <- c("var1","var2")
```
```{r print_table,echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
print(xtable(table,include.colnames=TRUE))
```
````

Comment: Could you add an example document demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @mvkorpel Added an example there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Tyler, I went browsing the knitr issues page and learned that xtable has an argument to suppress the comments (upvote to Tyler for that). It is a bit hard to use because you have to pass the argument to xtable's print method. The code that solves my problem looks like:

`print(xtable(table,include.colnames=TRUE),comment=FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

We can resolve this permanently by setting an `xtable` option:

```
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
```

See `?print.xtable`; since the `comment` argument defaults to `getOption("xtable.comment", TRUE)`, any calls to `print.xtable` will thereafter exclude the comment. Much credit due to [mnel on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400308/how-to-remove-the-lines-in-xtable-table-output-by-knitr) for suggesting to do it permanently.

Answer (score 3):

This is an xtable issue: xtable is designed for use within a LaTeX source document, and when you try to use it in a Markdown document instead, the formatting of comments becomes difficult to control as it passes from Md -> pandoc -> LaTeX -> pdf. There is some discussion on the [knitr issues page](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-book/issues/3). Knitr now includes the function <kbd>kable</kbd> to deal with simple tables. Alternatively, you could use a wrapper to strip the comments from xtable:

```
tyxtable <- function(x, trim = 2) {
    tmp <- textConnection(capture.output(xtable(x), file = NULL))
    tmp <- readLines(tmp)
    tmp <- tmp[-1:(-1 * trim)]
    writeLines(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the knitr issues page. I found out there that xtable was updated in version 1.71 to include an option to suppress comments. I did some browsing in xtables' documentation  and learned that all I had to do was to add the argument comment=FALSE to the xtable call.

Comment: This approach works nicely for `Hmisc::latex` as well!